# Getting the stream position where failbit was set / std::ios::failure was thrown

Tags: c++, stream, position

I need to parse a file and get the failure position if there is one. The problem is `tellg()` is useless if `failbit` is set.

Is there an elegant (built-in?) way to find the position at which `failbit` was set?

#### UPD

Is it valid to use `clear()` and `tellg()`? I can't find if the stream's state (including position) is guaranteed to remain valid after failure

Comment: After a `clear`ing a failure you can keep reading the stream from the point of failure, so the position must be preserved. This sometimes leads to another failure when the parser once again tries to read the data that could not be parsed. Somehow you have to remove the bad/unexpected data. Typical solutions `ignore` one token length or switching to a different parsing state to look for different data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not do-able if the stream has gone out of scope by the time the exception is handled. If the stream is still in scope, you can `clear` the failbit and then, if you need to, use `setstate` to reset failbit.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream test("10 20 thirty 40 50");
    test.exceptions(std::istream::failbit);

    try
    {
        int val;
        while (test >> val)
        {

        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Went boom.\n";
    }
    test.clear();
    std::cout << test.tellg();
    // test.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `clear` the stream so you can use `tellg()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("input.txt");

    std::vector<int> data{ std::istream_iterator<int>(infile), {} };

    infile.clear();
    std::cout << "failed at position: " << infile.tellg();
}
```

Of course, this will only work with a stream that supports `tellg` (meaningfully) to start with. If, for example, you tried to use it with `std::cin` instead of an `fstream`, you wouldn't get meaningful results (returns -1 with the compilers I've tested, but I haven't looked to be sure that's guaranteed).